# How does GZipStream determine the size of compressed data

Tags: c#, gzipstream

I have two files (I use 7zip): *n1.txt.gz* and *n2.txt.gz*. Then I combine them to the file *n12.txt.gz* by command prompt:

```
type n1.txt.gz > n12.txt.gz
type n2.txt.gz >> n12.txt.gz
```

If I decompress the file *n12.txt.gz* by 7zip, I will get combined decompressed original files (n1.txt + n2.txt).
But if I use this code

```
public static void Decompress2(String fileSource, String fileDestination, int buffsize)
{
 using (var fsInput = new FileStream(fileSource, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
 {
  using (var fsOutput = new FileStream(fileDestination, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
  {
   using (var gzipStream = new GZipStream(fsInput, CompressionMode.Decompress))
   {
    var buffer = new Byte[buffsize];
    int h;
    while ((h = gzipStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
    {
     fsOutput.Write(buffer, 0, h);
    }
   }
  }
 }
}
```

I will get just decompressed first part of *n12.txt.gz*, i.e. decompressed *n1.txt*.

Why does GZipStream stop after first part of combined file? And how does 7zip decompress the whole file?

Comment: I actually doubt that combining gzipped files works as you say...

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar it works. Just try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GZipStream does not implement methods to decompress multiple files from one stream.

Try using a library which handles ZIP archives such as [DotNetZip](https://dotnetzip.codeplex.com/).

If you absolutelly wanto to use GZipStream you could search the input stream for [the gzip header](http://www.zlib.org/rfc-gzip.html#file-format) and then feed GZipStream only the portions of the stream belonging to each file.

Comment: Ok. Thanks.
However, I've read gzip format. If I write the size of each portions to gzip header I'll read the portions and GZipStream will be decompress them correctly. But _7zip_ decompress my _n12.txt.gz_ file, and the file have no the size of portions. Do you know how _7zip_ do it?

Comment: No I don't know how 7zip does it but I think they might just assume your archive is broken and try to make the best of it.
Have a look at [how ZIP archives are structured](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zip_%28file_format%29#Structure) and you will see that your method misses the file directory necessary to identify where each file starts.